# serialize a json using gson

Tags: json, gson

I am using com.google.gson.JsonObject to send the json inside 'parameters' to a rest endpoint.

```
{
 "parameters": 
   "{
     \"customer\" : {
                       \"firstName\": \"Temp\",
                       \"lastName\": \"Temp\",
                       \"emailAddresses\": [\"temp1@temp.com\"],
                       \"address\": {
                                      \"street1\": \"123 W Temp St\",
                                      \"city\": \"Temp\",
                                      \"state\": \"Illinois\",
                                      \"zipCode\": \"61122\"
                       }
                    },
     \"options\" : [\"tv\"]
   }"
 }
```

Since Parameters is a json string, I am trying to do this :

```
    JsonObject json = new JsonObject();
    json.addProperty("options", ??);
```

I am not sure how to do it for customer and options.
'options' is a java Set, whereas customer is an object.

Answer (score 0):

You may use:

```java
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = "{\"parameters\": {\"customer\" ... ";
JsonObject jsonObject = gson.fromJson(json, JsonObject.class);
JsonArray options = new JsonArray();
options.add("tv");
jsonObject.add("options", options);
String output = gson.toJson(jsonObject);
```

Comment: for customer java object, can we do jsonObject.add ("customer", customerObject)